# Android - Button's textColor with a ripple effect

Tags: android, button, ripple, textcolor

Is there a possible way to make a button's text have a ripple effect? When I set ripple.xml on textColor of a button, it occurs an error. I've searched a lot, but I could only find information about button's background with a ripple effect.

Comment: this might work (android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground")

Comment: I don't think it seems to work

Comment: i see you want to have a ripple effect of the text rather than the the whole button. i dont think thats possible but not 100% sure.

Comment: Yes, only the button's text, I think i might need to create custom one

Comment: I dont think thats possible either. Even if you do a Textview that looks like a Button it will ripple the whole thing. Try anyway. You may resort into doing  a blank button and framelayout on top that has a TextView. Then you can ripple the Text with (android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"‌​)

Comment: give this a test -- do a textView with (android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default") and (android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"‌​‌​) -- it will probably ripple the whole thing but give it test anyway

Comment: Can u post your ui?